# TFS on premise deploy website to same machine

Tags: iis, tfs, webdeploy, winrm

I am trying to deploy a website to the same machine it was built on. It builds everything correctly and then gets stuck at this line. `Deployment started for machine: 192.168.1.201 with port 5985.` I get the error message that I cannot connect to the remote machine. I am very confused on how to get this last step setup.
Image of setup for WinRm deploy - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QztM2.png)

Comment: provide Admin User & PWD and try again

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) extension on TFS 2017. From your screenshot, you may need to check the items below and correct them to have another try.

In **Machines** parameter, try to specify comma separated list of machine FQDNs/IP addresses along with **port**.

In **Admin Login** and **Password** parameters, you need to specify a domain or Local administrator and corresponding password of the target host.

In **Web Deploy Package** parameter, you need to specify the location of the web deploy **zip** package file on the target machine or on a UNC path that is accessible to the administrator credentials of the machine.

Detailed documentation for this task you can refer to this website: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploy/README_IISAppDeploy.md

Comment: When reading the guide on how to setup WinRM it states that I will need a minimum of two machines. Is that the cause of my problem. My setup my TFS on premise is being hosted on the same server as the VS 2015 agent.

Comment: No. You can deploy to the same machine where the build agent runs. It works on my side. You need to check all parameters in your task, and check what error from "System.Exception: Error Code:" during deployment.